# NullPointerException in spark-sql

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdata

I am writing a program to join two files on a common parameter using spark-sql. I think my code is fine but when I am trying to save it as a text file then I am getting errors. I am putting my code as below:-

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.JavaSQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.JavaSchemaRDD;



import java.io.Serializable;


public class JoinCSV {
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class CompleteSample implements Serializable {
        private String ASSETNUM;
        private String ASSETTAG;
        private String CALNUM;



        public String getASSETNUM() {
            return ASSETNUM;
        }
        public void setASSETNUM(String aSSETNUM) {
            ASSETNUM = aSSETNUM;
        }
        public String getASSETTAG() {
            return ASSETTAG;
        }
        public void setASSETTAG(String aSSETTAG) {
            ASSETTAG = aSSETTAG;
        }
        public String getCALNUM() {
            return CALNUM;
        }
        public void setCALNUM(String cALNUM) {
            CALNUM = cALNUM;
        }


      }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class ExtendedSample implements Serializable {

        private String ASSETNUM;
        private String CHANGEBY;
        private String CHANGEDATE;


        public String getASSETNUM() {
            return ASSETNUM;
        }
        public void setASSETNUM(String aSSETNUM) {
            ASSETNUM = aSSETNUM;
        }
        public String getCHANGEBY() {
            return CHANGEBY;
        }
        public void setCHANGEBY(String cHANGEBY) {
            CHANGEBY = cHANGEBY;
        }
        public String getCHANGEDATE() {
            return CHANGEDATE;
        }
        public void setCHANGEDATE(String cHANGEDATE) {
            CHANGEDATE = cHANGEDATE;
        }
    }

    private static final Pattern comma = Pattern.compile(",");
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String path="C:/Users/cyg_server/Documents/bigDataExample/AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv";
        String path1="C:/Users/cyg_server/Documents/bigDataExample/AssetsImportExtendedSample.csv";

          JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext("local[2]", "JavaSparkSQL");
          JavaSQLContext sqlCtx = new JavaSQLContext(ctx);

          JavaRDD<CompleteSample> cs = ctx.textFile("C:/Users/cyg_server/Documents/bigDataExample/AssetsImportCompleteSample.csv").map(
                  new Function<String, CompleteSample>() {
                    public CompleteSample call(String line) throws Exception {
                      String[] parts = line.split(",");

                      CompleteSample cs = new CompleteSample();
                      cs.setASSETNUM(parts[0]);
                      cs.setASSETTAG(parts[1]);
                      cs.setCALNUM(parts[2]);

                      return cs;
                    }
                  });

          JavaRDD<ExtendedSample> es = ctx.textFile("C:/Users/cyg_server/Documents/bigDataExample/AssetsImportExtendedSample.csv").map(
                  new Function<String, ExtendedSample>() {
                    public ExtendedSample call(String line) throws Exception {
                      String[] parts = line.split(",");

                      ExtendedSample es = new ExtendedSample();
                      es.setASSETNUM(parts[0]);
                      es.setCHANGEBY(parts[1]);
                      es.setCHANGEDATE(parts[2]);

                      return es;
                    }
                  });

          JavaSchemaRDD complete = sqlCtx.applySchema(cs, CompleteSample.class);
            complete.registerAsTable("cs");

          JavaSchemaRDD extended = sqlCtx.applySchema(es, ExtendedSample.class);
          extended.registerAsTable("es");

          JavaSchemaRDD fs= sqlCtx.sql("SELECT ASSETTAG, CALNUM FROM cs INNER JOIN es ON cs.ASSETNUM=es.ASSETNUM;");
          fs.saveAsTextFile("result");                   //Here I am getting error
    }

}
```

and my errors are as below:-

```
    14/07/19 00:40:13 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0.0:0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Exception failure in TID 4 on host localhost: java.lang.NullPointerException
            java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
            org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:404)
            org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
            org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
            org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:678)
------------
------------
```

and

```
 14/07/19 00:40:11 ERROR Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
    java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:278)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:293)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:76)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:362)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$22.apply(SparkContext.scala:546)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$22.apply(SparkContext.scala:546)
-----------------
-----------------
```

This second error is coming everywhere whether I am using spark, spark-sql or spark-streaming. I have no clue what this error is. But it seems that this second error has no impact on the code because even after this error the results use to come out fine. But still its very irritating to see an unknown error everytime you run a program.

Can anybody please help me out in understanding the issue please? I am stuck with this very badly. Thanks

Comment: Do you get the same error on Linux?

Comment: No, Here I am trying to use "saveAsTextFile" to save the file on local file system on windows OS.Here for local file system none of the "saveAs" option is working. However these options are working very perfectly while saving the files on hdfs.

Comment: Looks like a Windows-specific issue to me. I don't know how to fix it, but if it's just local saving, you can work around the problem. Fetch the data with `RDD.collect()`, then save it via a regular Java `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: yeah, I found that many others are also facing similar issue so I think its kind of bug or may be its code is not written properly. Anyways I will try regular java for now. Thanks

Comment: Update:- I guess its not the problem of spark-sql but the "JavaRDD.saveAsTextFile("path/to/file")" itself have problem. By using this method I am able to create directories on my local file system abd the files are also getting created in them but no text is getting written in those files. Ans I am getting "NullPointerException".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a work around for the `rdd.saveAsTextFile()` error on Windows.  It fixes both the `SparkException` and `IOException` errors that I was also experiencing with Spark v1.1.0 on Windows 8.1 in local mode.

http://qnalist.com/questions/4994960/run-spark-unit-test-on-windows-7

Here are the steps from that link:

1) [download compiled winutils.exe](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/28a57efb-082b-424b-8d9e-731b1fe135de/please-read-if-experiencing-job-failures?forum=hdinsight);

2) put this somewhere like `c:\winutil\bin`;

3) add this line to your code: `System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "c:\\winutil\\")`

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much Dylan for providing this fantastic solution. I have ignored the winutils WARN message that seamed not related with saveTextAsFile. Now that I have followed your steps my application worked smoothly till the end.

Comment: @DylanHogg Hi sir can you please help me with this while saving to cassandra   i have problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042545/getting-sometimes-nullpointerexception-while-saving-into-cassandra/53048177#53048177