# Getting sometimes NullPointerException while saving into cassandra

Tags: apache-spark-sql, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I have following method to write into cassandra some time it saving data fine.
    When I run it again , sometimes it is throwing NullPointerException
    Not sure what is going wrong here ... Can you please help me.

```
'
  @throws(classOf[IOException])
  def writeDfToCassandra(o_model_family:DataFrame , keyspace:String, columnFamilyName: String) = {
    logger.info(s"writeDfToCassandra")

    o_model_family.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .options(Map( "table" -> columnFamilyName, "keyspace" -> keyspace ))
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .save()
  }

'
18/10/29 05:23:56 ERROR BMValsProcessor: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1283)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:309)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:229)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1093)
    at scala.util.matching.Regex.findFirstIn(Regex.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$redact$1$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(Utils.scala:2698)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$redact$1$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(Utils.scala:2698)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$redact$1.apply(Utils.scala:2698)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$redact$1.apply(Utils.scala:2696)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.redact(Utils.scala:2696)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.redact(Utils.scala:2663)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$$anonfun$redactOptions$1.apply(SQLConf.scala:1650)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf$$anonfun$redactOptions$1.apply(SQLConf.scala:1650)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:124)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.redactOptions(SQLConf.scala:1650)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.simpleString(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.QueryPlan.verboseString(QueryPlan.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.generateTreeString(TreeNode.scala:556)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.treeString(TreeNode.scala:480)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$4.apply(QueryExecution.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$4.apply(QueryExecution.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.stringOrError(QueryExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toString(QueryExecution.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
    at com.snp.utils.DbUtils$.writeDfToCassandra(DbUtils.scala:47)
```

Comment: @Alexott sir any clue what am I doing wrong here

Comment: @jrook sir any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly this is failing in the "redact" function of the Spark Utils. This is used on options that are potentially passed to Spark to remove sensitive data from UI's and such. I can't imagine why a null key-name would pop up in your SqlConf (since I believe you can only have Empty Strings) but I would check there. Could be a mutation of the conf while the method is being executed?

Comment: thank you for your quick reply sir. Me not sure about these "redact" settings.I am new to spark stuff... here is the config i set up .... https://gist.github.com/shatestest/7b0c0723d000a4e84d2aeb58352cf445 .... In one case i need to create and save RDD into cassandra ...for the I set config options apart from setCassandraConf...

Comment: sir any clue of what went wrong here and what is the fix. I am stuck here . I would be very thankful for fixing this issue

Comment: That's what I said already, the error is a npe in the spark uis redaction code. It attempts to react things like password or secrets. It does this by matching a regex against certain config keys. Somehow one of these keys was null

Comment: sir when i run for single query/process it is running fine. i.e. with same setting and configs. When these processors run them in parallel  for map , i am getting this issue. i.e.  
  ' 
  
 'https://gist.github.com/shatestest/86ae9559c6114999e13a6eec3c80ec2b#file-driver-scala

Comment: i am getting this issue. i.e.    '  val procs :  LinkedHashMap[String, (DataFrameReader, SparkSession, String) => Unit] = getAllDefinedProcessors();
       for ( key <- procs.keys){
            procs.get(key).map{
                println("process started for loading column family : " + key);
               fun => fun(ora_df_options_conf,spark,columnFamilyName)
         }
 'https://gist.github.com/shatestest/86ae9559c6114999e13a6eec3c80ec2b#file-driver-scala

Comment: sir I downloaded the spark-catalyst_2.11-2.3.1-sources.jar ...where should i look into ? i.e. any specific configuration parameters i need to check ? If you give some clue i will debug and try to provide work a round solution

Comment: sir i debugged it , there was table name going as null string , i fixed it...thanks a lot for your time , sorry to trouble you.

Comment: Sir you guys developed cassandra in Java lang...but spark-c*-connector in scala language why ? any specific reasons or advantages you find? in other words what issues you see with java in this use-case ?

Comment: Spark is written in Scala, so we wrote the connector in Scala. Some things are more difficult to do from Java because we still haven't flushed out Java wrappers for some of the scala things. It is possible to use Scala from java though so it's not a big deal most of the time.