# How to use accumulators with spark 2.3.1 api

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, databricks, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using spark-sql_2.11-2.3.1 version with Cassandra 3.x.
I need to provide a validation feature which has

```
   column_family_name text,
    oracle_count bigint,
    cassandra_count bigint,
    create_timestamp timestamp,
    last_update_timestamp timestamp,
    update_user text
```

For the same I need to count the successfully inserted record count i.e. cassandra_count to be populated , for that I want to make use of spark accumulator. But unfortunately I am not able to find required API samples with spark-sql_2.11-2.3.1 version.

Below is my saving to cassandra snippet

```
 o_model_df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
    .options(Map( "table" -> columnFamilyName, "keyspace" -> keyspace ))
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .save()
```

Here how to implement accumulator increment for each row being successfully saved into Cassandra ...

Any help would be highly thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark's accumulators are usually used in the transformations that you write, don't expect that spark cassandra connector will provide you something like.

But overall - if your job had finished without error, then it means that the data is written correctly into database.

If you want to check how many rows are really in the database, then you need to count data in the database - you can use [cassandraCount](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md#counting-rows) method of the spark cassandra connector.  The main reason for that - you may have in your DataFrame multiple rows that could be mapped into single Cassandra row (for example, if you incorrectly defined primary key, so multiple rows have it).

Comment: sir i am kind of stuck here ... not sure it working fine with one query/processor but not two or more ? any clue what am i doing wrong here    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042545/getting-sometimes-nullpointerexception-while-saving-into-cassandra/53048177#53048177

Comment: i got source code i can debug give me some clue where i can check it.

Comment: sir I debugged it , there was table name going as null string , i found it...thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: sir regarding cassandraCount , it get all the table count instead of recently inserted row count , but i need to get recently inserted count in cassandra...how should i implement that logic ?.... i.e in ETL we would have reject records and inserted records right ? similar way i want to implement ....how should i approach the design for it ?

Comment: sir one small doubt , in CQL there is something called "counter" type... can it be useful in my above case ? you think of anyway I can use it in my use case ?

Comment: sir i have only count() in this API , i dont find cassandraCount()       ' spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
     .options(Map( "table" -> columnFamilyName, "keyspace" -> keyspace ))
     .load()
     .count()    '

Comment: `cassandraCount` is the RDD API, not the DataFrame

Comment: sir when calling count() we must call load() transformation first i.e. records are fetched to RAM then counted on top it , am I correct ? then it would be poor in performance compared to cassandraCount() which run at C* , and count() would make use of Catalyst optimizer , ...  which one gives better performance ??? confused.

Comment: this really hard to say without testing... `cassandraCount` could be more optimized than count on DataFrame... the `load` doesn't actually load the data - it only marks them for loading, and actual load happens when action is executed

Comment: Thank you sir, for all your prompt reply ,  time and patience